# Create a dictionary from a given string in a text file

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a file with a string in this format: .B:13&A:4&I:1&I:!&H:|-|&H:}{&B:!3&H:[-]&&

It begins with a "." ends with a "&", separates each entry key-value pair with a "&" and finally separates each key from its corresponding value with a ":"
This is what I have so far:

// read the data
`filehndl = open("text.dat")
filedata = filehndl.read()
filehndl.close()`

but I'm not sure how to strip and split the data to create the dictionary. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Search for `python split` `python dict from list` and search, there is a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the first and last characters with:

```
filedata = filedata[1:-1]
```

Then split with:

```
entries = filedata.split('&')
```

Then split entries up and put them in a dict:

```
out_dict = {}
for entry in entries:
    entry_array = entry.split(':')
    out_dict[entry_array[0]] = entry_array[1]
```

So altogether you have

```
filehndl = open("text.dat")
filedata = filehndl.read()
filedata = filedata[1:-1]

entries = filedata.split('&')

out_dict = {}
for entry in entries:
    entry_array = entry.split(':')
    out_dict[entry_array[0]] = entry_array[1]

# out_dict is what you now want to work with

filehndl.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question again, i'm getting an index out of range error at out_dict[entry_array[0]] = entry_array[1]

Comment: I'm assuming you've gotten it figured out from the other responses, but for the edification of others: the second to last ampersand also needed to be stripped, so the third line should be `filedata = filedata[1:-1]`

Comment: I'm still getting a little confused about why i'm getting the IndexError for the last line of the for loop

Comment: You can gain some insight if you print `entries` - it has one additional empty entry at the end, which then doesn't give you a 2-element list if you try to split it around `:`.

Comment: Ahh which is why you meant the third line should be 'filedata = filedata[1:-2]'

Comment: Exactly! This will get rid of the last 2 characters instead of the last one.

Answer (score 1):

1 liner version assume your filedata will be 1 liner also

1st split the dict items by `&` after strip off the `.` and `&`, then built the dict splitting the key value pair by `:`

```
filedata = r'.B:13&A:4&I:1&I:!&H:|-|&H:}{&B:!3&H:[-]&&'
d = dict( i.split(':') for i in filedata.strip('.&\r\n').split('&') )
# {'A': '4', 'I': '!', 'B': '!3', 'H': '[-]'}
```

but this does not take care the repeated items with same key, for example, you have repeated key `B`, the later `B:!3` will override the previous `B:13`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your file only has one single line and that you aren't handle quoting, so then you can do it with a generator comprehension:

```
with open("yourfile.txt") as file:
    data = file.read().strip()
    if data.startswith(".") and data.endswith("&"):
        clean = data.lstrip(".").rstrip("&")
        print dict(item.split(":") for item in clean.split("&"))
```

The important line here, is:

```
dict(item.split(":") for item in clean.split("&"))
```

This is going to split your string by the `&` character, and then split again by `:` character, to finally "convert" the list in a dictionary.